# How to disable Java extension mechanism

Tags: java

Our product is a stand-alone OS X desktop application written in Java. We include an embedded JRE to run our software.

The rules for JRE startup seem to put any JAR  files in `/usr/lib/java`, `/Library/Java/Extensions`, and `~/Library/Java/Extensions` on the classpath BEFORE the libraries we explicitly include on the classpath.

If a user has any JAR files in any of the Java extension mechanism folders, then those JAR files get added to our classpath. A recent support incident arose because a customer had an older version of a critical third-party library in `/usr/lib/java` - this was causing our software to crash unexpectedly at startup.

I've been unable to determine how I can disable this extension mechanism when invoking the JRE embedded in our app. How can I do this?

<sup>─────────

NOTE: it seems that this extension mechanism is deprecated and will eventually be removed: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under)</sup>

Comment: I think you can specify -Djava.ext.dir to point to an safe location. Not sure if this works with the Mac launcher, it worked on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean that you package embedded JRE in **your** own jar file ? How do you package/include your embedded JRE?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer. First thing comes to my mind is modifying your JRE's security policies. Classes will be loaded with several calls to loadClass method, load behaviour depends on the security policies.

Comment: @Germann it is a lot more complicated than that - a small native stub invokes the JRE packaged in our app to launch our main JAR.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do anything to combat a mere installation error. Just be aware of the problem, document it in release notes and installation instructions, and be ready for it in support.

Comment: @EJP
That works for Enterprise applications, Not for consumer applications.

Answer (score 11):

You can override the `"java.ext.dirs"` JVM argument to point to some application directory.

I tested overriding JVM Argument and it works fine.

```
$ ls /Library/Java/Extensions
extentionstest.jar
$
$java ExtentionTest
Main method executed fine.
$
$ java -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/pratapk/work/ ExtentionTest
Error: Could not find or load main class ExtentionTest
$
```

And the `ExtentionTest` class is built into `extentionstest.jar` and copied at `/Library/Java/Extensions`

```
public class ExtentionTest {
    public static void main(String args[] ) {
        System.out.println("Main method executed fine.");
    }
}
```

`java.ext.dirs` supports multiple directory as colon separated. In your case the **JRE is included along with your app**, It is much easier for you include the path of `lib/ext` while not including `"/Library/Java/Extensions"`

Comment: This achieves what I requested. However upon trying it, it seems that the extension mechanism is currently critical for loading nashorn and JavaFx. We need to be able to prevent only the /usr/lib/java folder from being used; the embedded JRE's lib/ext folder must be included.

Comment: java.ext.dirs supports multiple directory as colon separated. In your case the JRE is included along with your app, So It is much easier for you include the path of lib/ext while not including "/Library/Java/Extensions"